# C++ cannot assign to return value because function 'operator []' returns a const value

Tags: c++, breadth-first-search

Hi every one I'm new to C++, and practicing it by leetcode.
Today when I was trying lc127, this error confused me. This error comes from one ranged for statement, where variable first is of the type unordered_set. And if I removed the reference mark&, then it works all right.
The most minimal reproducible example is like:

```
            unordered_set<string> first{ beginWord }, last{ endWord };
            int i = 0, j = 'a';   
            for (auto& word : first) {
            word[i] = j;//error here
            }
```

And the error shows:

```
Line 17: Char 33: error: cannot assign to return value because function 'operator[]' returns a const value
                        word[i] = j;
                        ~~~~~~~ ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/basic_string.h:1045:7: note: function 'operator[]' which returns const-qualified type 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>::const_reference' (aka 'const char &') declared here
      const_reference
      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My question is that why the former version is wrong? To my understanding, if I want to change the value in a ranged for statement, then I should use a & to ensure that I changed the value?

Full code link:[Full code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFAFB.jpg)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please edit your code into the question as text along with any errors you're receiving.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks for your comment. I have already modified it.

Comment: Elements in an `unordered_set` are const because of the way the container works. If you were able to modify them it would invalidate the hash.

Comment: "And if I removed the reference mark&, then it works all right. "  Then you're copying the elements, so the modification works on a local copy.  The set itself is unchanged.

Comment: The value of the elements in a set cannot be modified once in the container (the elements are always const), but they can be inserted or removed from the container. Source: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/ Same applies for unordered_set